# Change the root directory of the assets from vue build

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I'm using Vue CLI 3.3 and building vue projects for my vertical website, but every time I build the project, the assets of  `dist/index.html` always load from my root path, like:

```html
<script src=js/chunk-vendors.b0f460c7.js></script>
```

Is there a way to make these assets load from current path? Such as

```html
<script src=./js/chunk-vendors.b0f460c7.js></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `publicPath` in your `vue.config.js` (see https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath)

```js
module.exports = 
{
  publicPath: './',
};
```