# Js files on wrong location after vue build

Tags: javascript, npm, vuejs2, build

I have two very similar projects, both base codes work on top of the same package/vueConfig files, yet, when I build one of the projects, I'm getting a bunch of js files outside the js folder, which is what I need to fix.

[image: lots of]

Already checked solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62506888/change-the-root-directory-of-the-assets-from-vue-build) and checked documentation but still getting the same output.

Here is the scripts part of my package file

```
"scripts": {
"serve:vlox": "env APP_TYPE=vloxEditor vue-cli-service serve vloxEditor/src/main.js",
"build:vlox": "env APP_TYPE=vloxEditor vue-cli-service build vloxEditor/src/main.js",
"serve:res": "env APP_TYPE=resourceEditor vue-cli-service serve resourceEditor/src/main.js",
"build:res": "env APP_TYPE=resourceEditor vue-cli-service build resourceEditor/src/main.js"
},
```

and my vue.config

```
var fs = require('fs');

const path = require('path')

const appDir = process.env.APP_TYPE;

module.exports = {
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, `${appDir}/dist`),
  publicPath: `./${appDir}-assets`,
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.resolve.alias.set('@I', path.resolve(__dirname, '../interfaces'))
    config.resolve.alias.set('@shared', path.resolve(__dirname, './shared'))
    config.plugin("html").tap(args => {
      args[0].template = path.resolve(__dirname, `${appDir}/index.html`)
      return args
    })
  },
  devServer: {
    "port": 9090,
    "https": {
      "key": fs.readFileSync('../../vue-res/certs/ssl.key'),
      "cert": fs.readFileSync('../../vue-res/certs/ssl.crt')
    },
    proxy: {
      '^/vlox': {
        target: 'https://172.25.37.144',
        changeOrigin: true
      },
    }
  }
}
```

My general project structure is as follows

[image: Project structure]

Comment: Can you search in your entire project for `vloxEditor`?

Comment: @kissu sure, it's right on the project root, only folder, no file, the projects are organized based on this https://dev.to/hamishclulee/one-build-system-multiple-vue-apps-shared-components-283d

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to ace and how it internally loads the different components, which is dynamic, and leads to all the junk on the main folder, lucky [this](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-build-generating-tons-of-chunk-files/46914/4) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630205/using-a-webpack-plugin-with-vue-client-3) gave the right idea.

This is the vue.config.js I used to fix the issue

```
var fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const appDir = process.env.APP_TYPE;

module.exports = {
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, `${appDir}/dist`),
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/^file-loader\?esModule=false!(.*)/, (res) => {
        res.request = res.request.replace(/^file-loader\?esModule=false!/, 'file-loader?esModule=false&outputPath=assets/js/ace-editor-modes!')
      }),
    ],
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.resolve.alias.set('@I', path.resolve(__dirname, '../interfaces'))
    config.resolve.alias.set('@shared', path.resolve(__dirname, './shared'))
    config.plugin("html").tap(args => {
      args[0].template = path.resolve(__dirname, `${appDir}/index.html`)
      return args
    })
  },
  devServer: {
    "port": 9090,
    "https": {
      "key": fs.readFileSync('../../vue-res/certs/ssl.key'),
      "cert": fs.readFileSync('../../vue-res/certs/ssl.crt')
    },
    proxy: {
      '^/vlox': {
        target: 'https://172.25.42.163',
        changeOrigin: true
      },
    }
  }
}
```

And now all the ace stuff is on its own folder

[image: fixed deployment]